# CGI permissions with NGINX & FastCGI

Tags: nginx, fastcgi, file-permissions, cgi, git

I'm running GitWeb (which is essentially a CGI script) on a server which also runs GitLab. My aim is to provide reaad-only access to GitLab repositories without registering people.

I've pointed GitWeb to my repositories folder which have permissions `drwxrws---` with owner:group `git:git`. FastCGI wrapper is running with user:group `www-data:www:data`, so I added `www-data` to `git` group. I also verified access of `www-data` to repositories by changing to that user.

However, when I run GitWeb, CGI script cannot access to repositories and cannot get my list of repositories. Everything works fine if I add `r-x` permissions to other part (last triplet) but I don't want to mess with permissions of the folders because of obvious reasons.

Btw, I'm running Debian stable and didn't install SE-Linux or something similar.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found and fixed the problem. Actually it's a bug in nginx.

Normally, under `nginx.conf`, there's a user directive which sets the nginx's `setuid()`/`setgid()` behavior & the syntax of the directive is `user <username> <groupname>`. Doucmentation[1] states that, if you omit `<groupname>`, `<username>` will be used as group. However, that's not the case and nginx defaults to group `nobody`. When I added the group `www-data` explicitly, everything started to work as it should.

[1] http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#user